# Pre-calculate hash of a data block

Tags: java, c#, algorithm, hash

I want to implement a collaborative download scheme, whereby 2 or more peers download parts of a file from a server that supports http byte range scheme.
The file can then be combined and all users can have the original file complete.
Now here's my problem:
Is there a way to pre-calculate the hash for each data block/range before it is downloaded, such that if a peer's download is corrupted, the requesting peer can confirm that by comparing the hash on the downloaded and transmitted block with the hash pre-calculated before the file was downloaded?

This has several use cases: Imagine knowing which block in a torrent download is corrupted rather than waiting for a whole file/folder to get downloaded?

Comment: which language you will use? java or C#?

Comment: Yes, there is a way ... just handle a list of hashs for each chunk and **every** peer can check this hash to detect corrupted chunks.

Comment: Have you considered using Bittorrent?  It's a beautiful protocol for distributed downloading, and sounds like exactly the kind of features you're looking for.

Comment: I am trying to implement a collaborative download with pre-check hash function for the data blocks.. language used does not matter. I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: @SirRufo, How do I get this list of hashes? How do I pre-calculate the hash for a data block? That's my question

Comment: How do the files come into this system? Somewhere is the starting point with the original file. Split this file into chunks and build the hash from each chunk. Now you have the hashes. On every transfer send the chunk and the hash and every receiver will check the hash. Doing so, no peer will send corrupted data.